# How to support older Java dependencies after methods have been removed?

Tags: java, reflection, minecraft

I am writing a plugin for Minecraft which uses WorldEdit. There is a class `BlockVector3` with methods `getBlockX()` and `getX()` which are deprecated and marked for removal, to be replaced by `x()`.

The problem is that if I use the new method, users who are using an older version of WorldEdit will no longer be able to use my plugin. And if I retain the deprecated method, it will soon cease to function with the latest dependency.

I could write two different plugins. However, is there a way to work around this particular issue using reflection or some other introspection?

Comment: Are you using gradle or maven?

Comment: Neither. I build my jars using a makefiles.

Comment: if its possible you can use classloader and load your own class (instead of the original) which supports both versions.

Comment: Why not just write your own method?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

1. **One class per version**, tricky but easy.

It's a common way to do it. Mostly, people do an interface like this :

```java
public interface WorldEditAdapter {
   void load();
   void doSomething(double x, double y, double z);
}
```

Then, create a new class for each version like this:

```java
public class WorldEdit3 implements WorldEditAdapter {
   public void load() {
       // load everything related to WorldEdit 3
   }
}

public class WorldEdit4 implements WorldEditAdapter {
   public void load() {
       // load everything related to WorldEdit 4
   }
}
```

Then, in the `onEnable()`, firstly check for which version is used, then instanciate it with `new WorldEdit3()` for example, then save it as `WorldEditAdapter`. Now, your full plugin will use `WorldEditAdapter`.

---

About how to use method not available, if you don't have compilation plugin, maybe you can import multiple file to "fake" the existance of method for 2 versions. This could be tricky.

You can also use reflection as you mentionned. It's not preferable. To use it, do:

```java
myObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getX").invoke(myObject); // equivalent of myObject.getX();
```

Static call of method:

```java
MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod").invoke(null); // equivalent of MyClass.myMethod();
```

2. **Gradle/Maven: sub projects**.

With gradle and maven it would be easier. You can do solution 1 but by putting the `WorldEdit3` in different subproject loaded by the main one. It would be easier to manage, but it's not your case.